# In C++, when is destructor called automatically for local vector?

Tags: c++, vector

For example, say I have the following code:

```
vector<vector<int>> big;
for (int i=0;i<3;++i){
    vector<int> small;
    small.push_back(3*i+1);
    small.push_back(3*i+2);
    small.push_back(3*i+3);
    big.push_back(small);
}
for (vector<int> s:big){
    for (int a:s){cout<<a<<" ";}
    cout<<endl;
}
```

The cout gives result that big contains the value for vector small in each for loop, I am confused because I thought the vector small will be destructed automatically in each for loop.
Why does the big still have access to the correct value?

Thanks!

Comment: It *is* destructed, but when you are pushing it to the big vector, it's *copied*.

Comment: And then, it is copied again when you say `for (vector<int> s : big)`. Probably not relevant to this question but best to avoid in general. Prefer `for (auto& s : big)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute:

```
big.push_back(small);
```

a copy of `small` is added to `big`. You can verify that they are two different objects by executing the following:

```
std::cout << (void*)&big.back() << std::endl;  // big.back() returns a reference to the copy.
std::cout << (void*)&small << std::endl;
```

You can also verify that they hold the data of the vectors independently. You can print the pointers that hold the data.

```
std::cout << (void*)big.back().data() << std::endl;
std::cout << (void*)small.data() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you used `big.push_back(small);` which made a copy of small vector and when small vector was destroyed at the end of the loop the copy was not effected

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<T>::push_back()` is **copy-based**. It creates a copy of the argument, which in this case is `small`,  and stores it in `big`.

So you're NOT seeing the elements from `small`, but from `big` actually.